# Will calling pthread_cond_signal(...) then calling pthread_cond_wait(...) wake up the waiter?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

so I've searched online a bit for an answer and nothing seems to clearly answer it. My question is simple, I need, say, 5 worker threads to enter a queue and then signal their boss thread (thread 6) that they are all in the queue ready for work. Due to the way the rest of my program works it would be best if what I want to accomplish actually works, with that said:

So if I have the boss thread hit the lock, see that the queue is not *completely* full, the boss will `pthread_cond_wait(...);` and wait until it is full. Now, all the workerthreads will enter the queue and hit a wait, and once the final thread enters he will signal the master and then wait. So in between when the final worker signals to when he hits his wait will the boss still wait until the final helper hits the wait? Because I don't want the boss to do anything until that last thread is actually waiting. So the final thread will **not** be hitting a `pthread_mutex_unlock(...)` he will be hitting a `pthread_cond_wait(...)` and I want to verify that this will wake us the boss. Thanks in advance, I hope my question is clear, I tend to over-explain everything :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boss can wait n times for signals sent by the workers. Every time it waked up, it checks the queue length and if it is not full waits again.
It is better to use semaphore in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If the "boss thread" is blocked in `pthread_cond_wait()`, it can't continue executing until it can re-acquire the mutex that was passed to that function.

So, if the thread that has signalled the boss thread is holding that mutex, the boss thread won't continue until the signalling thread releases the mutex - which can either be through `pthread_mutex_unlock()` or `pthread_cond_wait()` (which releases the mutex while waiting).